# pl /sql procedure execution giving an error

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

My stored proc is defined as

```
create or replace procedure TEST(
     name  IN table1.col_name%type,
     price IN table1.col_price%type
)
is
begin
    update table1  t set t.name =name where t.price = price;
commit;
end TEST;
```

I am trying to execute it as

```
exec TEST(name => 'John', price => 1000);
```

However, it gives invalid SQL error. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input parameter `%type` statements claim the column names are `col_name` and `col_price`. But that is not how you refer to them in your stored procedure (`name` and `price`).

Bad things can happen when you name variables after column names. [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:6729304326802) recommends a limited convention of variable naming conventions:

- local variables start with  `L_`
- parameters start with `P_`
- global package variables start with `G_`

That link has a good general discussion on PL/SQL naming conventions. I personally just use `V_` for most variables (aside from indexes and other obvious things), but that's just me.

Lastly, the `col_` in the column names seem redundant; simply use `name` and `price` as column names.

So, that said, I think this does what you want:

```
create table table1 (
    name    varchar2(30),
    price   number
);

create or replace procedure TEST(
     p_name  IN table1.name%type,
     p_price IN table1.price%type
)
is
begin
    update table1 
       set name = p_name 
     where price = p_price;
    commit;
end TEST;
/
insert into table1 values ('John', 500);
commit;

select * from table1;

exec TEST(p_name => 'Bob', p_price => 500);

select * from table1;

-- Clean up test artifacts
drop procedure test;
drop table table1;
```

Giving the output:

```
table TABLE1 created.
PROCEDURE TEST compiled
1 rows inserted.
committed.
NAME                                PRICE
------------------------------ ----------
John                                  500 

anonymous block completed
NAME                                PRICE
------------------------------ ----------
Bob                                   500 

procedure TEST dropped.
table TABLE1 dropped.
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the variable prefixing approach. Oracle don't do it with their own API's, and it would be extraordinarily irritating if they did. It always seems like a workaround, rather than a fix.

For me the fix is to namespace the variables with the procedure name. It keeps the argument names "clean" and makes your code 100% proof against capture:

```
create or replace procedure TEST(
  name  IN table1.col_name%type,
  price IN table1.col_price%type)
is
begin
  update table1 t
  set    name    = test.name
  where  t.price = price;
commit;
end TEST;
```

Lots more info on capture [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/nameresolve.htm#LNPLS017).